# Mock StoredProcedureQuery with Mockito NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am testing service layer in Spring Boot Application in following manner :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ADPTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ADPsService ADPsService;
    @Test
    public void getADPsDetails() {
        ADPsStoredDetails e = new ADPsStoredDetails();
        e.setAlert(STRING_VALUE);
        e.setTsid(STRING_VALUE);
        
        List<ADPsStoredDetails> ADPsStoredDetails = new ArrayList<ADPsStoredDetails>();
        ADPsStoredDetails.add(e);

        EntityManager targetEm = mock(EntityManager.class);
        StoredProcedureQuery query = mock(StoredProcedureQuery.class);
        Mockito.when(targetEm.createStoredProcedureQuery("dbo.getADPsinfo","ADPsDetails")).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(ADPsStoredDetails);
        
        List<ADPDTO> actionsDTO =  ADPsService.getADPsDetails();
        assertTrue("List has values", actionsDTO.size() > 0);

    }
    }
```

The method i am testing has following signature

```
public List<ADPDTO>  getADPsDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StoredProcedureQuery ADPsDetailsStoredProcedure = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery(
                "dbo.getADPsinfo","ADPsDetails");
        
        List<ADPsStoredDetails> results = ADPsDetailsStoredProcedure.getResultList();
        
        Map<String, List<ADPsStoredDetails>> result = results.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ADPsStoredDetails::getTsid));

        List<ADPDTO> ADPDTO = new ArrayList<ADPDTO>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<ADPsStoredDetails>> entry : result.entrySet())  {
            ADPDTO e = new ADPDTO();
            e.setTsName(entry.getKey());
            e.setAlerts(entry.getValue());
            ADPDTO.add(e);
        }
```

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` in service method at

```
StoredProcedureQuery ADPsDetailsStoredProcedure = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery(
                "dbo.getADPsinfo","ADPsDetails");
```

Kindly help regarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't create `Mock` instances for the `InjectMocks` to inject. Move creation of `targetEm` as an instance variable.

```
@InjectMocks
private ADPsService ADPsService;

@Mock
private EntityManager targetEm;
```

Comment: I will do it but had a question, what difference does it makes..If i am using mock method to mock entitymanager and storedprocedurequery? I just updated the mock method import in above section.

Comment: You have it as a local variable and @InjectMocks can't pick from it.

Comment: ohh.thank you.so same needs to be done for storedprocedurequery too?

Comment: No. It doesn't need to be and it can be local as it is a result that gets returned for `manager.createStoredProcedureQuery` call. In other words, it is not a dependency for your SUT